# Kendo-label is not a known element

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, label, kendo-angular-ui

I’m using kendo switch inside a kendo label and it is throwing error. And I have imported label module in app.module.ts as well.

```
import {LabelModule} from '@progress/kendo-angular-label'

<kendo-label text="Initial value:">
  <kendo-switch [(ng-model)]="checked"></kendo-switch>
</kendo-label>
```

Added the import to app module file and to imports but the error is throwing like this.

Comment: if you're using Angular (not AngularJs) should be `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: Thanks Eliseo, it’s a typo , looking for kendo label error

Comment: Tony, the modules only should be import in Modules (if you're not using standalone components). And should be imported in the module where your component is declared. NOTE I imagine that the quotes are also typo